# How to get TGroupBox themed caption font color

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I would like to get the font color of a TGroupBox caption, so I can assign that color to a TLabel.

I think I need to use [`GetThemeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773397%28VS.85%29.aspx), but I can't seem to figure out which parameters to use?

---

Update - This is the code I use based on the answer:

```
function GetGroupBoxTextColor: TColor;
var
  C: COLORREF;
  ElementDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  Result := clWindowText;
  if ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
  begin
    ElementDetails := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(tbGroupBoxNormal);
    if GetThemeColor(ThemeServices.Theme[teButton], ElementDetails.Part, ElementDetails.State, TMT_TEXTCOLOR, C) = S_OK then
      Result := C;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this works:

```
var
  h: HTHEME;
  clr: COLORREF;
begin
  h := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
  if h <> 0 then
    try
      OleCheck(GetThemeColor(h, BP_GROUPBOX, GBS_NORMAL, TMT_TEXTCOLOR, clr));
    finally
      CloseThemeData(h);
    end;
```

(uses `OleAuto, UxTheme`)

Comment: What is `Handle` refer to? the Form?

Comment: @ZigiZ, yup, it's most probably meant to be the form handle.

Comment: @user539484: Thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately, I have always believed this to be the correct way to do things, and I am not sure what I should do instead. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm using the same and now I'm confused a bit as well. Neither `OpenThemeData` nor `CloseThemeData` reference doesn't explicitly says that you must close that handle. But the note in the `CloseThemeData` I understand as that you should call it when a window *which uses the theme handle for its rendering* is destroyed (or when the `WM_THEMECHANGED` message is received). So, I would say it should be taken as the other system object handle - when you open it, take care to close it and in that case is what we use the safest way. @user539484, what do you think ?

Comment: @Andreas, easiest way how to *workaround* this is IMHO use what ZigiZ shown in his answer update and simply ask `ThemeServices` (now deprecated) to give you a [`Theme`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Themes.TCustomStyleServices.Theme) handle for a specified element. `ThemeServices` will then take care to close all the opened handles at `Themes` unit finalization.

Comment: Well, this code construct implies what `GetThemeColor` can throw an exception, but it can't. Instead, it can return negative `HRESULT`, which case is never checked for. @TLama, here is business as usual, you've acquired an object - you are responsible for releasing it.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't matter whether you call CloseThemeData or not. OpenThemeData returns some kind of a pseudo handle and closing theme data does not have any effect on a handle that is later to be opened. Perhaps it would matter if you closed the theme data on the last window of the system (for this example).

Comment: Pesonally, I do not believe what HTHEME leackage can reek any havoc, but I would still write a code like it can because it is a good habit :-)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, just surround the call with `OleCheck` and the exception frame will find its use.